# SQL - Request from a movie database to get all the movies and their details

Tags: mysql, sql

I found similar questions but quite different in the end, and none answers my problem.

I use mySQL

I have a table movie_artist_role liking 3 tables movie, artists and role containing the 3 keys

```
mo_id
ar_id
ro_id.
```

The table movie contains

```
mo_id
mo_title
```

the table artists contains

```
ar_id
ar_name
```

the table role contains

```
ro_id
ro_name (actor or producer for instance)
```

I want to display the list of the films, and for each films the actors and the director(s)

What is the most efficient way to get that? Is it possible in one unique query with multiple left join?

Thanks

Comment: sounds like this might be homework. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
select movie.mo_title, artist.ar_name, role.ro_name
from movie_artist_role 
left join movie on movie.mo_id = movie_artist_role.mo_id
left join artist on artist.ar_id = movie_artist_role.ar_id
left join role on role.ro_id = movie_artist_role.ro_id
order by movie.mo_tile, artist.ar_name
```

I have a similar movie database! I think that the 'role' table as you have defined it is unnecessary - I have a separate 'directors' table which links directly to the 'movies' table: it's very rare to have two directors for the same moview, and when there are (eg Cohn brothers), they tend to work together frequently, so they can be regarded as one director.

Using left joins as opposed to inner joins allows one to display movies which don't have a director or actors linked to it.

Comment: yeah but you also have the producer etc... and they can all be the same artist, the same person

Comment: @cam: so what? The schema which you are suggesting would mean that  you would need multiple joins on the 'artist' table in order to represent the actors, directors and producers.

Comment: Ok, the query works pretty well, and I can see the table I get, but how can I use it to display it correctly? I have to do other queries on this result?

Comment: Thanks Newman for your help, but I must say I'm a bit lost :)

Comment: @Cam you could put any `query` into a `stored procedure`, and then use a another query with a `where` clause to pull information returned from the `sp`.

Comment: @Killrawr this sounds interesting, how would it works a stored procedure in this case for example?

Comment: @Cam Stored procedures reduce network traffic and improve performance. That’s because you are only sending the stored procedures name (and possibly parameter values) across the network and not the entire set of SQL statements. The Server then runs (executes) the procedure and sends only the result set back to the client’s machine. I'm not sure at the moment on how it would help with this case, but it was just a suggestion.

Comment: @cam: Forget my comment about multiple joins. Your schema is ok as it stands - you could have three rows having the same movie and artist, but each row having a different value for the role. But if there are only three roles (actor, director, producer), then it would be easier to move the role into the join table thus obviating the need for the 'roles' table.

Comment: @cam: when you write "I have to do other queries on this result", what do you mean? If you want to know who is connected to a specific film or in which films appeared a specific actor, then you need to add a 'where' clause to the query.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple `inner join` (will pull everything from all 3 tables) between the connected `foreign keys` would display a list of information foreach film, actors and directors.

```
SELECT * FROM movie_artist_role mar
INNER JOIN movie m ON mar.mo_id = m.mo_id
INNER JOIN artists a ON mar.ar_id = a.ar_id
INNER JOIN role r ON mar.ro_id = r.ro_id
ORDER BY m.mo_title, r.role_name
```

Using a `WHERE` clause would give you specifics on that film or actor. For example..

```
SELECT * FROM movie_artist_role mar
INNER JOIN movie m ON mar.mo_id = m.mo_id
INNER JOIN artists a ON mar.ar_id = a.ar_id
INNER JOIN role r ON mar.ro_id = r.ro_id
WHERE a.ar_name = 'Jack Black' ORDER BY m.mo_title, r.role_name
```

If you only want specific data from a specific table say `film` then... its pretty much what was done above but in reverse.

```
SELECT * FROM movie m
INNER JOIN movie_artist_role mar ON mar.mo_id = m.mo_id
INNER JOIN artists a ON mar.ar_id = a.ar_id
INNER JOIN role r ON mar.ro_id = r.ro_id
ORDER BY m.mo_title, r.role_name
```

or `artists`...

```
SELECT * FROM artists a
INNER JOIN movie_artist_role mar ON mar.ar_id = a.ar_id
INNER JOIN movie m ON mar.mo_id = m.mo_id
INNER JOIN role r ON mar.ro_id = r.ro_id
ORDER BY m.mo_title, r.role_name
```

etc etc

Comment: In this case, I want all the films, and the problem is to display what I get correctly...

Comment: @Cam I've updated my answer for a specific table. :) That should meet your needs. Regards

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOINS should work just fine.

```
SELECT m.mo_title AS movie_title, 
       (SELECT group_concat(aIn.ar_name)
        FROM movie_artist_role AS marIn
            LEFT JOIN role AS rIn ON rIn.ro_id = marIn.ro_id
            LEFT JOIN artist AS aIn ON aIn.ar_id = marIn.ao_id
        WHERE rIn.ro_name = 'producer'
            AND marIn.mo_id = m.id ) AS producers,

       (SELECT group_concat(aIn.ar_name)
        FROM movie_artist_role AS marIn
            LEFT JOIN role AS rIn ON rIn.ro_id = marIn.ro_id
            LEFT JOIN artist AS aIn ON aIn.ar_id = marIn.ao_id
        WHERE rIn.ro_name = 'actor'
            AND marIn.mo_id = m.id ) AS actors
FROM movie AS m
```

This is untested, but should return rows such as:

```
movie_title       |      producers       |     actors
-----------------------------------------------------------
Star Treck          JJ Abrams               Chris Pine, Simon Pegg, Zachery
```

Comment: Yes so I get let say 3 lines by films, 2 with an actor role, and 1 for the director. How can I retreat the data efficiently to display it easily? i.e. foreach movie, echo movie[id][director]  etc...

Comment: Heavily edited my answer to what I hope is what your looking for.  I'll test it in the morning and post an update if it isn't 100% correct, but it should point you in the right direction